# ArcMap, Network analyst data preparation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, linear-referencing

I have line feature class with pedestrian network ... and information about network parameters (surface type, surface quality, slope, etc. ... not in digital form now). I want to create network dataset for routing.
Is the only solution using them as attributes of line feature class (it means splitting lines into very short segments) or any other solution exists (something like linear referencing and dynamic segmentation)?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the data? I think I follow, but am unsure: You have two tables--one with gis data and one with attributes, you want to be able to do route/network analysis through the GIS data, but not want to split to where they have differences in attributes...how are you currently joining the attribute table to the GIS data?

Comment: I have line feature class with pedestrian network ... and information about network parameters (surface type, surface quality, slope, etc. ... not in digital form).
Is the only solution using them as attributes of line feature class (it means splitting lines into very short segments) or any other solution exists (something like event tables in linear referencing? I didn´t find any.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide these additional details.  It certainly sounds like linear referencing to me.

Comment: I do not think that Network Analyst can use the attributes without assigning them directly to a line feature class.  However, you still could use LR to assign limits for each single attribute in separate tables to create the longest segments possible for each attribute, and then use the Overlay Route Events to combine those tables into a single event table that is broken into short segments at every attribute change.  You can then export the events into your network dataset as a line feature class and then add that as a network feature class.  It isn't much more work than just doing LR.

Comment: Thanks for help, Richard. I was thinking about my problem the wrong way ...

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.